# XML layout editor

Tags: android, layout, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to android programming, but one thing that I can't seem to get down is writing the XML files.  I use a program called droiddraw to help generate the xml code.  This program is very simple because it lets me add buttons and DRAG them where I want them.  Once I get the screen/form (or whatever it's called) setup the say I like, it will generate the the xml file for me.  My question is this:  "Does eclipse have a plugin  that will do that too?"  I know that I can view the form/screen that I can designing, and add buttons and such, but I can't drag them to where I want them.  I always have to edit the layout values manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml layout editor that ships with Eclipse is pretty woeful. Thankfully Google are putting effort into improving this so that we have a more seamless drag n drop experience. You can download and compile the latest works here http://tornorbye.blogspot.com/2010/11/building-android-ide-tools.html

or just wait a week (or two) for Gingerbread to be released. A stable version is sure to be included in the Eclipse ADT update that is released then.

Comment: Great, sounds like this is what I was looking for.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) is nicely integrated into Eclipse for Android development.